# Android, Null Pointer Exception to Data that isn't null

Tags: android, xml, null, nullpointerexception

I'm writing an app for android that needs to parse data from an XML file. I've never come across an error like this that is so impossibly hard to track down. Or maybe my brain just stopped working. That happens. XML file is of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<memberRoster>
    <agent>
        <agentInfo1>...</agentInfo1>
        <agentInfo2>...</agentInfo2>
        ...
    </agent>
    <agent>
        ...
    </agent>
    ...
</memberRoster>
```

So far it's working well, except for some random bits of fun!

Every now and then it will throw a NullPointerException. I did some more digging and found out that there are THREE "agents" (out of 800) with "supposedly" null data. I checked the XML file and the data is there, there are no illegal characters, etc. It is the same three "agents" every time. The program parses other entries before and after these "null" "agents". Also of note is that not all "agentInfo" fields in the ArrayList come up null; example, one of the entries has 7 of the 8 entries as null, with the 8th one non-null, another has only one null with the last 7 non-null.

I'm parsing the data in to an ArrayList from the XML file, and like I mentioned before, it works flawlessly until it comes to those three specific entries in the XML file.

I'm sorry I can't give much more info than that, the data is sensitive to our members.

EDIT:

Sorry! I knew I was forgetting something! :)

Some code from my XMLHandler.java class:

`public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)`

```
    if(this.in_mr_agentNrdsId) {
        agent[0] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentFirstName) {
        agent[1] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentLastName) {
        agent[2] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentPhone) {
        agent[3] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentEmail) {
        agent[4] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentOfficeName) {
        agent[5] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentOfficePhone) {
        agent[6] = ch.toString();
    }
    else if(this.in_mr_agentType) {
        agent[7] = ch.toString();
        pds.setMemberRoster(agent);
        agent = new String[8];
    }
```

PDS is an object of type ParsedDataSet, which is just a simple class containing the ArrayList objects and a few getter and setter methods:

`public class ParsedDataSet {
    private ArrayList agentOpenHouses = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList calendarOfEvents = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList latestStatistics = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList memberRoster = new ArrayList();`

```
public ArrayList<String[]> getAgentOpenHouses() {
    return agentOpenHouses;
}

public ArrayList<String[]> getCalendarOfEvents() {
    return calendarOfEvents;
}

public ArrayList<String[]> getLatestStatistics() {
    return latestStatistics;
}

public ArrayList<String[]> getMemberRoster() {
    return memberRoster;
}

public void setAgentOpenHouses(String[] agentOpenHousesItem) {
    this.agentOpenHouses.add(agentOpenHousesItem);
}

public void setCalendarOfEvents(String[] calendarOfEventsItem) {
    this.calendarOfEvents.add(calendarOfEventsItem);
}

public void setLatestStatistics(String[] latestStatisticsItem) {
    this.latestStatistics.add(latestStatisticsItem);
}

public void setMemberRoster(String[] memberRosterItem) {
    this.memberRoster.add(memberRosterItem);
}
```

} // end class ParsedDataSet

Comment: Post some code so we can help.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code for retrieving and parsing the XML

Comment: Can you give a stacktrace from LogCat, and perhaps the offending snippet of code?

Comment: Added some code. Let me know if more is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw an if statement into your assignements and reassign any caught 'NULL' or empty strings into a zero value or just reassign as variable = "" in your code.

For example:

```
if (agentInfo1 == NULL) {
    agentInfo1 = "" || agentInfo1 = 0; //Depending on what your variables are
}
```

Comment: That's just the thing, the data in the ArrayList should NOT be null. There is really no reason I can think of as to why it would be, as the data is there in the XML file, and the program is able to parse 99% of the file correctly. It's almost like the compiler has something against these specific agents ;)

Comment: Are there special characters in the agent fields? 
Also as nicholas hauschild mentioned, a logcat from the adb interface would really help pinpoint the error.

Comment: Negative, I have removed any and all special characters server-side, so they are not even in the XML file. Also, the ArrayList indexes in question have no formatting to speak of, no periods, commas, etc. to begin with. I will get you a logcat shortly.

Comment: Well as a quick test, you could remove those 3 agents from your XML file and see if the parser is failing on those 3 agents or those 3 positions in the XML file. That could give another vantage point to where the error is occurring.

Comment: JKMach - thanks for the ideas. I removed those 3 entries, and reran the app, and it gave me similar problems - strange thing was it was the same indexes (index 315 and 714 of the ArrayList!). I removed those, and the problem went away. Strangely enough, when I re-instated the original XML file, it went off fine. As of now I'm going to consider this question answered, but will do more bug testing on this feature before releasing the app.

Comment: Awesome to hear that you were able to nail down where the error was occurring (that it was erroring on the indexes and not those agents).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting try catch loop in code to find where the error is happening, then, pinpoint the exact part of code that is giving this error, there do null checks before proceeding. This is based on best practices of software development, rather than a fix for you.

Alternatively, you can makes sure on server side that there are no "null" values, maybe by giving dummy value like "EMPTY_STRING". This is especially relevant if your app is already shipped and you cant make any client code changes.

Comment: I have verified that server-side null checking is done, and there are no empty fields in the XML file - I have replaced any "null" field with whitespace, which, excluding the three above-mentioned ArrayList indexes works great. I'm working on posting some code.